# Использование статического класса для передачи данных между формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Для передачи данных между разными формами или формой и консолью я использую статический класс ,в котором объявляю переменные,которые нужно передать . Не нарушает ли такое решение  ООП или какие-то законы "правильного построения кода"? Возможно лучше использовать присвоение владельца  ? (Не в плане эффективности ,а "правильности")

```
.Owner = ***;
```

Хочется узнать мнение более опытных программистов по этому поводу.

Comment: Нарушает. Становится сложно тестировать.

Comment: Конечно нарушает, Owner тоже так себе вариант. Я бы предпочел юзать IoC контейнеры для этого. Но если у вас приложение на полторы формы, то абсолютно без разницы, как вы решите свою задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Статический класс, как и глобальные переменные, сильно затрудняет понимание взаимосвязей между другими классами и усложняет тестирование.

Допустим, мы создаём экземпляр некоторого класса вызовом конструктора и вызываем его метод:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var result = foo.DoWork();
```

При этом полагаем, что получим желаемый результат. А результата нет. Почему?

Оказывается, этот класс внутри себя использует данные из статического класса (глобальные переменные).

```
public int DoWork()
{
    return _x * StaticClass.A + _y * StaticClass.B;
}
```

То есть перед вызовом этого метода мы должны задать нужные значения этому статическому классу:

```
StaticClass.A = 5;
StaticClass.B = 10;
var result = foo.DoWork();
```

Можно ли об этом догадаться, глядя на интерфейс класса? Нет. Узнать об этом мы можем только изучив внутренности класса. Или прочитав сопроводительную документацию, но кто ж её читает (и пишет)?..

---

А вот если принимаемые параметры будут задаваться явно либо в конструкторе, либо в методе, то это сразу видно и невозможно их не задать:

```
public Foo(int a, int b)
{
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
}

public int DoWork()
{
    return _x * _a + _y * _b;
}
```

Вызов:

```
var foo = new Foo(5, 10);
var result = foo.DoWork();
```

Или:

```
public int DoWork(int a, int b)
{
    return _x * a + _y * b;
}
```

Вызов:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var result = foo.DoWork(5, 10);
```