# Глобальные переменные в формах visual studio c#

Tags: c#

Как сделать глобальную переменную для её изменений в разных формах.Где именно её объявлять?

Comment: Статическое поле/свойство в любом классе. Но имейте ввиду, что такое - признак плохого дизайна.

Comment: Лучше всего все статические переменные и константы, общие для нескольких форм, вынести в отдельный класс, который лежит вне файлов форм.

Comment: Ассоциация [Правильное использование синглтона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768396/179763)

Comment: Не используйте глобальные переменные. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991276/184217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, реализуется через простой "паттерн" Static Holder, например:

```
public static class Holder
{
   public static int Variable1 { get; set;}
}
```

Соответственно, обращение из разных форм будет `Holder.Variable1`

Советую на досуге почитать про Singleton, например [здесь](https://medium.com/@sinethneranjana/5-ways-to-write-a-singleton-and-why-you-shouldnt-1cf078562376)

Comment: Ссылка у вас на Java пример. К C# имеет посредственное отношение, т.к. построение Singleton классов немного иное. Исправьте или удалите.

Comment: @Rootware, да, ссылка на Java, но там, по моему, очень доходчиво расписано. Поэтому я и посоветовал почитать про сам паттерн, а не посмотреть реализацию.

Comment: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) - описание реализации одиночки от самого Джона Скита.

Comment: Это медвежья услуга с вашей стороны. Мало того, что описание на английском, так ещё и не для указанного языка. В итоге вы "предлагаете осциллограф вместо телевизора ориентируясь только по наличию экрана". Хотите помочь, дополните вопрос описанием синглтона на русском в общих чертах, чтобы задающий вопрос человек при необходимости сам почитал про это. Я бы не стал вам делать на это замечание, если бы не имел практики использования последних как в Java, так и в C#.

Comment: Вы во многом правы, но категорически не согласен по поводу английского языка. Я убежден, что минимальное знание английского (для чтения технической документации) абсолютно необходимо. А поскольку я посоветовал прочитать про паттерн, язык программирования, ИМХО, не столь важен. Важно понимание его работы, что в статье написано неплохо.